# How to Add Pre-existing Tags to Select2 in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

HTML:

```
<select data-placeholder="Skill List" style="width:100%;" class="chzn-select form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option *ngFor="#skill of allSkills" [ngValue]="skill">{{skill}}
    </option>
</select>
```

TS:

```
allSkills = ['Welding', 'Forklifting'];
selectedSkill = ['Welding'];

ngOnInit(): void {
    jQuery('.chzn-select').select2();
}
```

How to add the **selectedSkill** initially?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel) binding to the `select` tag:

```html
<select data-placeholder="Skill List" 
        [(ngModel)]="selectedSkill" 
        style="width:100%;" 
        class="chzn-select form-control" 
        multiple="multiple">

    <option *ngFor="#skill of allSkills" [ngValue]="skill">
        {{skill}}
    </option>

</select>
```

And in your code:

```ts
allSkills = ['Welding', 'Forklifting'];
selectedSkill = allSkills[0]; // or just 'Welding'

ngOnInit(): void {
    jQuery('.chzn-select').select2();
}
```